# Nuitka - compiling module including precompiled .so libraries

Tags: python, numba, nuitka

I need to use both nuitka (code obfuscation) and numba (code optimization), but nuitka crashes when executing `@njit` (understandable).

My idea is to precompile some code with numba using it's AOT compiling feature, so nuitka can use it later when doing it's thing.

Issues I encountered :

- when leaving only the precompiled .so file, nuitka ignores it => `ImportError`
- when leaving source .py file with .so file, nuitka uses the .py file despite seeing both files

  - it displays a warning about finding both files
  - I tried adding `--no-prefer-source-code` (which should be default) but it still uses the .py file instead of the precompiled .so

**Did anyone at some point managed to import external .so modules in a nuitka process ?**

NB: I know, I can just copy the precompiled numba .so file and get it to be imported 'normally' by the compiled nuitka .so, but it's not scalable if I add more precompiled numba code in the futur.
The idea would be to include the precompiled numba .so inside nuitka's .so (is it even possible ?)